# jquery radio change with data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have radio group in my code like this:

```
<div id="question_1">
    <label for="q1_1a"><input name="q[1][1]" id="q1_1a" type="radio">A</label>
    <label for="q1_1b"><input name="q[1][1]" id="q1_1b" type="radio">B</label>
    <label for="q1_1c"><input name="q[1][1]" id="q1_1c" type="radio" data-target="#q1_2">Other</label>
        <input id="q1_2" name="q[1][2]" type="text" placeholder="specify">
</div>
<div id="question_2">
    <label for="q2_1a"><input name="q[2][1]" id="q2_1a" type="radio">A</label>
    <label for="q2_1b"><input name="q[2][1]" id="q2_1b" type="radio">B</label>
    <label for="q2_1c"><input name="q[2][1]" id="q2_1c" type="radio" data-target="#q2_2hide">Other</label>
    <div id="q2_2hide">
        Specify:
        <input name="q[2][2]" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

and so on...

I'm trying to write jquery code that would show data-target field when you check radio button that contains data-target attribute. So far I have something like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"][data-target]').change(function () { 
    $($(this).data('target')).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

It will show field, but it won't hide it once you select some other option. Any ideas?

Comment: Because onchange event is only fired for radio button on check, not when unchecked

Answer (score 1):

That's because onchange event is only fired for radio button on check, not when unchecked.
Here is more generic way to handle expected behaviour:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () { 
     $(this).closest('label').nextAll('input[placeholder]').toggle($(this).is('[data-target]'));
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: This works but in my case data-target is not always input field with placeholder. Sometimes it's div or some other element.